# С# EF Core. Не срабатывает update-database

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core

```
public class ModelContext : DbContext
    {
        public ModelContext()
        {
            Database.EnsureCreated();
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=.;Database=territory;Trusted_Connection=True;");
        }

        public DbSet<News> News { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    }
```

В `ConfitureServices` прописал `services.AddDbContext<ModelContext>();`

Сначала у меня была одна бд `Users`. Прописал `add-migration initial` и она создалась, потом нужно было добавить две остальные(по коду выше какие).
Прописываю `update-database` иии... `No migrations were applied. The database is already up to date.`
Базы, как уже ясно, не появляются кроме первой добавленной изначально.
Пробовал удалять папку `migration` и снова делать миграцию - не особо помогло. Что можно еще попробовать?

Comment: а вы второй раз `add-migration`, после добавления новых таблиц, вызывали?

Comment: @ExplodingKitten да там даже не второй а десятый раз вызывал)

Comment: а можно код миграции initial?